# Is Snow Muktza?

Tags: shabbat, muktzeh, weather

Does anyone know good sources that talk about this issue?  Perhaps we can divide this into 3 categories:

1. Is snow generally muktza since it has no practical use (as opposed to rainwater which has uses)?  Shmiras Shabbos Kehilchasa equates it to rainwater, but I personally see a distinction.
2. Does it matter if it fell before shabbos or on shabbos?
3. If falling on shabbos is more of an issue, does it matter if it fell into snow that was previously on the groung from before shabbos (Do we say Kamma Kamma Batel)?

From the lack of its discussion, it seems like it may not be a big issue.

Comment: Answers at a shour with sources here: http://www.torahanytime.com/scripts/media.php?file=media/Rabbi/Shlomo_Pearl/2010-01-10/Halachot_of_Snow_on_Shabbat/Rabbi__Shlomo_Pearl__Halachot_of_Snow_on_Shabbat__2010-01-10.wmv

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Shoveling Snow on Shabbos](http://hirhurim.blogspot.com/2008/12/shoveling-snow-on-shabbos.html)

Most authorities hold that snow is not Muktza on Shabbos, since it is not Nolad, as the moisture was in the air earlier. However according to "The Halachos of Muktza" in the name of HaRav Moshe Feinstein Zatzal snow is Muktza even if it fell before Shabbos since it is not normally used for anything, not even as food for animals.

Comment: Good sources!!!

Comment: Would you mind writing a two-sentence summary of that link?